# transpose selected rows of a column to one row with python

Tags: python, transpose

I have a file which contains values (one column) for each hour of the day (365 days in total). A part of the file is shown below:

[image]

How could I transpose the days (i.e. 24 hours) in one column so as to have finally a file with 365 rows and 24 columns.

In a simple case of transpose I would do the following

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(infile)
    df_transposed = df.T
    df_transposed.to_csv(outfile)
```

May I use a group for the selected hours and how?

Comment: maybe you could use something like:
    `df.iloc[:].T`
and in square brackets you specify the indices

Comment: @lunesco thank you, could you please specify what the indices would be in that case? Should I add a column with the id of the day (i.e. 1 to 365) ?

Comment: @lunesco also in case I use df.iloc[1:24].T I get only the first day (i.e. 24 hours) in one row. How do I specify to append the following days/rows?